# Spring RestController Async Results

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

The blog post http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs (as well as the referenced resources) recommend using the following scenario when using REST to wait for long running jobs

- Return the payload immediately if the result is already available when returning the requests. Looks like a standard request with status code OK.
- Respond with status code ACCEPTED and add a Location as well as an Async-Result header to let clients recognize that they should ...
- Poll the returned location using GET and wait until the Async-Result header changes either to Available or Cancelled.
- In case of Available a status code SEE_OTHER and another Location header is returned. Follow the location to get the result.

I known that I can return e.g. a `CompletableFuture` from a method, but this will block the request until the future is completed. Is there any support for such behavior in Spring MVC or is there any way I can enhance Spring MVC to implement this behavior, (e.g. implementing a `org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` ?)

Comment: You can already do this. Nothing prevents you from doing this with a regular `@RestController`... You would have 1 method that either returns 1 or 2. In case of 2 your client needs to poll the given URL (which you can implement). You don't need anything custom for this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behavior recommended in that blog post with Spring, you should *not* return the `CompletableFuture` from your controller unless that future is already completed (the status code should be `201` in this case).

Otherwise, you should build an empty response with just a `Location` header (containing the creation *task URL*) and a `202` status code and return that one instead, if `isDone()` returns `false` for your future.